# boundingRectWithSize returning a wrong height value for a multiline label

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am facing a strange problem with `boundingRectWithSize` and a multiline UILabel using the Swift language. I am currently working in a Xcode playground so I can see the result and updates of UI in real-time.

What I am trying to do is to calculate a given UILabel height dynamically based on it's content, I know this has been discusses over an over in other StackOverflow questions but this seems too strange to me.

The multi line label has this text in `NSAttributedString` form. Text is a simple Lorem ipsum placeholder:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor.

Here's the code for the `UILabel`:

```
let valueString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor."

var dataValue = UILabel()
dataValue.numberOfLines = 0
dataValue.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .Justified
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0.1

let attributedText = NSAttributedString.init(
    string:valueString,
    attributes:[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle, NSFontAttributeName:dataValue.font])

let textString = dataValue.text! as NSString

dataValue.attributedText = attributedText

dataValue.frame = CGRect(
                x:CGFloat(kMargin),
                y:dataType.frame.origin.y + CGFloat(kLabelHeight),
                width:CGFloat((maxLabelWidth) - kMargin * 2),
                height:textString.boundingRectWithSize(
                    CGSizeMake(CGFloat(kMaxWidth), CGFloat.max),
                    options:[.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, .UsesFontLeading],
                    attributes:[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle, NSFontAttributeName:dataValue.font],
                    context:nil).size.height)
```

The problem is that the UILabel only shows 3 lines of text, stopping at the **mauris** word of the text and truncating the last ones as you can see from the Playground preview feature:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem is that `valueString` and `textString` are two different strings. So there is no reason to believe that string you're putting into the label is the same as the string you're measuring.

You use `valueString` here:

```
let attributedText = NSAttributedString.init(
string:valueString, // ...
```

But you use `dataString` here:

```
height:textString.boundingRectWithSize(
```

Also, do not try to combine label attributes with attributed text. This can cause all kinds of problems. The `dataValue` label should have *no `font`*. You should not be fetching this `font` value. Do everything using the attributed string. You should not be constructing two different style dictionaries; you should be assigning and measuring the *exact same attributed string*.

To put it another way, do not measure `valueString` or `textString` at all, with or without attributes. Measure `attributedString`.

Finally, make sure that the label has the same width as you are using during measurement. You are saying

```
CGSizeMake(CGFloat(kMaxWidth) // ...
```

but there is no evidence that the label itself is going to have this width.

Comment: Hello @matt thank you for your answer, I have updated my question to make it explicit that I am reading the same text value

Comment: No you have not. I see no info in your question as to what `textString` might be.

Comment: Well, now you're just changing your code. So now I don't believe that what you say is your code is really your code. :)

Comment: Yes I know, you were right so I am updating it to better resemble the real situation here, I didn't copy-pasted my code correctly the first time I wrote the question. Can you please take a look now?